# Books for beginning type system theory

Tags: types, computer-science, type-theory

I want to study type system theory. I don't have any background in type system theory so I'm more or less a beginner (except the articles I've read on the subject and which I find intimidating because of the notation used). What are some good books that could get me started? I was looking at Benjamin C. Pierce's "Types and Programming Languages" book. Is that appropriate for a beginner or is it too difficult? If it's too difficult what else could I use to start my study?

Thanks,

--

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think Types and Programming Languages would be a good choice.

When I've first read TaPL, I was a beginner in type theory as well, and I didn't find it too hard to understand.

You will see a lot of the notation used in the articles you've seen, but the notation will be explained before it's used, so it shouldn't be a problem. There isn't really anything intimidating about the notation once you know what it means<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> Which is quite often the case with these things. Sometimes I think that most of mathematics and formal computer science consists of inventing scary-looking notations for simple things, so the uneducated masses don't realize how easy it all really is.

Comment: Inventing notation is about not having to write the same multi-word phrase 100 times in a 10-page paper, thereby blowing it up to 20 or 30 pages. For instance, the '≺' symbol means "is a subtype of", a 16 character long phrase. It's not about obscurity, it's about being able to get the message across at all.

Comment: @Novelocrat: I was mostly kidding about that.

Comment: Thanks sepp2k. Jokingly I'd be tempted to say the same :). I'll buy TaPL and start reading it.

Answer (score 4):

TAPL is a hard book to understand and is aimed at graduates (and possibly phd candidates). It's certainly not for beginners. I would instead recommend a book like 'Concepts in Programming Languages' by John C. Mitchell aimed at undergraduates to get yourself familiar with the basics first.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm only a beginner with type system theory :) I'm not new to programming languages and I've implemented my fair share of interpreters. It's just that I want to get more into the theoretical side of things.